# How can we solve the following matrix inequality?

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, bilinear-form, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $A$, $C$, $W$ and $V$ be given (known) matrices with $V$
and $W$ being semidefinite positive. We would like to determine the
matrices $X$ and $Y$ by solving the following inequality 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X & YC\\
0 & A
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}YVY^{T} & 0\\
0 & W
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}X & YC\\
0 & A
\end{bmatrix} &  & \begin{bmatrix}X & YC\\
0 & A
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}YVY^{T} & 0\\
0 & W
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}YVY^{T} & 0\\
0 & W
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}X & YC\\
0 & A
\end{bmatrix} &  & \begin{bmatrix}YVY^{T} & 0\\
0 & W
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\succeq0.
\end{equation}

Does anyone know how to
transform this inequality into linear matrix inequality (LMI) using Schur complements or other methods please?
Or does anyone know how to solve this inequality in order to determine
the matrices $X$ and $Y$ please? Thanks.

Comment: It might be useful to note that we can rewrite the matrix as the product
$$
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{X & YC\\0&A}\\ & I}^T
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{YVY^T\\ & W}^{-1} \\ & \pmatrix{YVY^T\\ & W}^{-1}}
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{X & YC\\0&A}\\ & I}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $P$ is positive semidefinite, then so is $A^TPA$ for any matrix $A$.

By rewriting our matrix as the product
$$
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{X & YC\\0&A}\\ & I}^T
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{YVY^T\\ & W}^{-1} \\ & \pmatrix{YVY^T\\ & W}^{-1}}
\pmatrix{\pmatrix{X & YC\\0&A}\\ & I}
$$
We can see that your matrix will be positive semidefinite whenever $V$ and $W$ are positive semidefinite.

Comment: @G.Trav edit the question; that's easier than writing a comment

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer Omnomnomnom. Excuse me really, I was not specific about the question. The real problem is the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326173/how-can-we-solve-this-matrix-inequality . It would be great to have your opinion on that please. Thanks for all.